# DynamoDB Limit on query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a doubt about `Limit` on query/scans on DynamoDB.

My table has 1000 records, and the query on all of them return 50 values, but if I put a `Limit` of 5, that doesn't mean that the query will return the first 5 values, it just say that query for 5 Items on the table (in any order, so they could be very old items or new ones), so it's possible that I got 0 items on the query. How can actually get the latest 5 items of a query? I need to set a `Limit` of 5 (numbers are examples) because it will to expensive to query/scan for more items than that.

The query has this input

```
{
  TableName: 'transactionsTable',
  IndexName: 'transactionsByUserId',
  ProjectionExpression: 'origin, receiver, #valid_status, createdAt, totalAmount',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'userId = :userId',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':userId': 'user-id',
    ':payment_gateway': 'payment_gateway'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#valid_status': 'status'
  },
  FilterExpression: '#valid_status = :payment_gateway',
  Limit: 5
}
```

The index of my table is like this:

[image]

Should I use a second index or something, to sort them with the field `createdAt` but then, how I'm sure that the query will look into all the items?

Answer (score 9):

> if I put a Limit of 5, that doesn't mean that the query will return the first 5 values, it just say that query for 5 Items on the table (in any order, so they could be very old items or new ones), so it's possible that I got 0 items on the query. How can actually get the latest 5 items of a query?

You are correct in your observation, and unfortunately there is no `Query` options or any other operation that can guarantee 5 items in a single request. To understand why this is the case (it's not just laziness on Amazon's side), consider the following extreme case: you have a huge database with one billion items, but do a very specific query which has just 5 matching items, and now making the request you wished for: "give me back 5 items". Such a request would need to read the *entire* database of a billion items, before it can return anything, and the client will surely give up by then. So this is not how DyanmoDB's `Limit` works. It limits the amount of work that DyanamoDB needs to do before responding. So if `Limit = 100`, DynamoDB will read internally 100 items, which takes a bounded amount of time. But you are right that you have no idea whether it will respond with 100 items (if all of them matched the filter) or 0 items (if none of them matched the filter).

So to do what you want to do efficiently, you'll need to think of a different way to model your data - i.e., how to organize the partition and sort keys. There are different ways to do it, each has its own benefits and downsides, you'll need to consider your options for yourself. Since you asked about GSI, I'll give you some hints about how to use that option:

The pattern you are looking for is called [filtered data retrieval](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-use-dynamodb-global-secondary-indexes-to-improve-query-performance-and-reduce-costs/). As you noted, if you do a GSI with the sort key being `createdAt`, you can retrieve the newest items first. But you still need to do a filter, and still don't know how to stop after 5 filtered results (and not 5 pre-filtering) results. The solution is to ask DynamoDB to only put in the GSI, in the first place, items which pass the filtering. In your example, it seems you always use the same filter: "status = payment_gateway". DynamoDB doesn't have an option to run a generic filter function when building the GSI, but it has a different trick up its sleeve to achieve the same thing: Any time you set "status = payment_gateway", also set another attribute "status_payment_gateway", and when status is set to something else, delete the "status_payment_gateway". Now, create the GSI with "status_payment_gateway" as the **partition key**. DynamoDB will only put items in the GSI if they have this attribute, thereby achieving exactly the filtering you want.

You can also have multiple mutually-exclusive filtering criteria in one GSI by setting the partition key attribute to multiple different values, and you can then do a `Query` on each of these values separately (using `KeyConditionExpression`).

Comment: Even though I have indexes, when I use limit on a query it doesn't return the number of items I specified in the limit. Can you help?

Comment: I'll have to see your specific data layout and query to know what's wrong....

Comment: I just need to know if I have a query with multiple condition, and I also use limit, which index should I specify in the query in order to return the amount of items requested in limit?